# How to force the active window\application to capture keyboard shortcuts before the OS does?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, manjaro

I tend to stick to default keyboard shortcuts so I don't have to configure my applications/system if I reinstall my system and applications.

But I sometimes find the OS capturing default applications keyboard shortcuts before my applications does, which basically neutralizes the shortcut and the application doesn't handle it. Simply because the OS did !

Is there a way to switch the cycle and give application the priority of handling keyboard shortcuts, and if the shortcut isn't handles, then the OS does ?

Comment: The OS controls the driver and the keyboard, so that should not be possible. You should be able to tell the OS to not act on the shortcuts you care about, and then they would go to the active Window = your app.

Comment: I'm sure there is a way because on `Eclipse` (And IDE), when I press `Alt+Shift+S`, it drops down a menu in the IDE, although pressing `Al+Shift` should switch languages. On `Windows`, `Eclipse` handles the shortcut, but not on `Manjaro`.